# Put in html tag value from javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to wrap r.title value with `<b></b>` tag.
I wanted to do so `r.subtitle && (l = "<b>" + r.title + "</b>" + r.subtitle)`, but displays it in text.

This function

```
function (e, t, n) {
        "use strict";
        function r(e) {
            return e && e.__esModule ? e : { default: e };
        }
        Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", { value: !0 });
        var o = n(0),
            a = r(o),
            i = n(1),
            l = r(i),
            u = function (e) {
                var t = e.className,
                    n = e.style,
                    r = e.track,
                    o = e.trackNo,
                    i = e.displayArtistNames,
                    l = r.title;
                return i && r.subtitle && (l = r.title + " - " + r.subtitle), null != o && (l = o + ". " + l), a.default.createElement("span", { style: n }, l);
            };
        (u.propTypes = { track: l.default.object.isRequired, trackNo: l.default.number, style: l.default.object, className: l.default.string, displayArtistNames: l.default.bool }), (t.default = u);
},
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .innerText property to set element's text or .innerHTML / .outerHTML to set the html-code inside or outside of html element tag:

```js
var elementCode = "<b>" + title + "</b>";
document.body.innerHTML += elementCode;
```

You can also use [create and append child functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) (more recommended)